# ipad frame max size is not enough

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm developing an ipad application about 2d drawing.
I need  a UIView.frame size of 4000x4000. But if I set a frame with size 4000x4000 the application
crash since i get memory warning.

Right night I'm using 1600*1000 frame size and the user can add new object (rectangle) on frame. User can also translate fram along x and y axis using pan gesture in order to see or add new object.

Have you got some suggestion?  how can I tackle this problem?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would suggest what is used in video games for a long time - creating a tiled LOD mechanism, where only when you zoom in toward specific tiles, they are rendered at an increasing resolution, while when zoomed out, you only render lower resolution.

Answer (score 0):

If the drawing in based on shapes (rectangles, points, lines, or anything can be represented by simple vector data) there is no reason to create a UIView for the entire size of the drawing. You just redraw the currently visible view as the user pans across the drawing using the stored vector data. There is no persistent bitmapped representation of the drawing.

If using bitmap data for drawing (i.e. a Photoshop type of app) then you'll likely need to use a mechanism that caches off-screen data into secondary storage and loads it back onto the screen as the user pans across it. In either case, the UIView only needs to be as big as the physical screen size.

Sorry I don't have any iOS code examples for any of this - take this as a high-level abstraction and work from there.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to be using UIScrollView.